# How to add sliding effect in services, skills, portfolio, etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a horizontal sliding effect in a website. This is more like 'WHO WE ARE', 'OUR SKILLS', 'OUR SERVICE', 'OUR PORTFOLIO' in the website: http://markline.org/
OR
Similar effect like 'WHAT CLIENT SAY' in http://greenacreinfracon.com/index.php

I wanted to add say 6 skills and when I clicked on the right arrow or at some time interval I want one skill from the left side to disappear the remaining 2 to move one container and a new skill appears in the last container

But I cannot seem to find any helpful tips. Please help me.
A little hint would be fine.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are you trying to slide in each menu item? Do you want the entire menu to slide in on page load? I can't tell what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Take a look at the website I have given, e.g. in 'OUR SKILLS' section when I clicked on the left arrow or right arrow new skills are about to appear (though they didn't add new skills), I wanted to add say 6 skills and when I clicked on the right arrow or at some time interval I want one skill from the left side to disappear the remaining 2 to move one container and a new skill appears in the last container.

Comment: Hope it clears my goals. Sorry about my unclear description.

Comment: @W.Kabir take a look in the plugin. It is the plugin they use in their website. You can use it for appear/disappear effects of your elements. It is really easy to use. You can explore the options in their main page dropdown

Comment: @W.Kabir I edited the answer and added the plugin they use for the moving skills part. Hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a big hint:

The site you referenced in your question uses ***animate.css*** plugin. You can use it like they do really easy if you follow these easy steps:

1. **Download** the plugin:

[From here](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

2. **Include** the stylesheet in your html page `<head>` section:

`<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

3. **Put the css classes** to the elements you want

You should always use the `animated` class and also choose class for the effect. You can see all the effect classes in their website main dropdown. In this case I chose slideInLeft effect:

`<h1 class="animated slideInLeft">Hello, World!</h1>`

### Appendix

Here is a working example for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.5.1/animate.min.css" 
     rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="animated slideInLeft">Hello, World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Edit: The slider in the website:

In the slider you are talking about this website uses ***bxSlider*** plugin

**Download** the plugin:

[From here](http://bxslider.com/)

**Include** the plugin in your html page `<head>` section (Include also jQuery before)

```
<link href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
```

**Make a container** with the sliding elements you want. This one is from their website:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
   <li><img src="/images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="/images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="/images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="/images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

**Init the bxSlider** on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

### Appendix

Here is a working example for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css"     rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.js">         </script>
<style>
        section {
            height: 300px;
        }

        section div {
            width: 300px;
            float: left;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bxslider">
    <section>
        <div>
            <img   src="http://static4.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_small/11/113268/2198841-house_stark.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Put here whatever you want 2
        </div>
        <div>
            <img  src="http://static4.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_small/14/148983/3088809-3914989654-Game-.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Put here whatever you want 4
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div>
            Put here whatever you want 1
        </div>
        <div>
            Put here whatever you want 2
        </div>
        <div>
            Put here whatever you want 3
        </div>
        <div>
            Put here whatever you want 4
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps. If you have any more questions I will be happy to help!

Comment: Thanks for you "big hint", this is the solution I was looking.